# How to hide options from dropdown based on what is selected on another multi-select

Tags: jquery

I have 2 drop-downs one is a single select and one is a  multi-select. Both have the same options to choose from. I want to dynamically hide all the options in the single-select that the user selected in the multi-select. For example, if the user selected in the multi-select "cat","dog","rat", I want the single-select drop-down should hide the options "cat","dog","rat"...

```
 $("#Project_AdditionalProjectManagerIds").on('change',
        function() {
            $("#Project_PrimaryProjectManagerId option").show();
            var itemToHide = $(this).val();
            var numberOfOptions = $("#Project_PrimaryProjectManagerId option").length;
            $('#Project_PrimaryProjectManagerId option').filter(function(){
                for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
                    for (var a = 0; i < itemToHide.length; i++){
                    if(numberOfOptions[i].val() === itemToHide[a] ) 
                      return true;
                }
                }
                return false;
            }).remove();
```

This is the HTML:

```
 <tr class="control-evenrow">
        <td class="control-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Project.PrimaryProjectManagerId, new {@class = ""})
        </td>
        <td class="control-input">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Project.PrimaryProjectManagerId, primaryProjectManagerList, "", new {@class = "chosen-select", placeholder = "Select..."})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Project.PrimaryProjectManagerId)
        </td>
        <td class="control-spacer-column"></td>
        <td class="control-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Project.AdditionalProjectManagerIds)
        </td>
        <td class="control-input">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Project.AdditionalProjectManagerIds, new MultiSelectList(Model.ProjectManagers, "Id", "FullName", Model.Project.AdditionalProjectManagerIds), new {@class = "chosen-select" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Project.AdditionalProjectManagerIds)
        </td>
```

I'm very new to programming and I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *This is what I tried so far, but nothing works.* ... if that is the only code you have of course is not working, you're showing us unfinished piece of code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @lonut I think I explained in detail exactly what I want to accomplish . I tried and could'n figure out how to do it since I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: @lonut Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I could try to help you if you post the whole relevant code.

Comment: @lonut I added the HTML related to this.  don't have more relevant code to this. Thanks.